# How to log when a particular memory location gets written and by which function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-corruption

I have a bug which happens very rarely but crashes my C++ program. It's seems I have a buffer overflow problem or something similar. I find that these types of bug are the most difficult to diagnose.

My program always crashes because of the same corrupted memory location. Is there some debugging tool which could detect when a particular memory location get written to and logs the function which does it?

I'm using Visual Leak Detector (VLD) for my memory leak hunting and it works great. It substitutes the original mallocs which its own and logs every allocation. I was wondering if there is something similar for memory?

I know that something like that would cripple a program, but it could be really helpful.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @Matthieu: (regarding edit comment) gcc and gdb work great on Windows, BSD, and OS X, too! :)

Comment: But doesn't a memory corruption issue risk being different if a different compiler is used ? I always thought gdb required the program to be compiled with gcc :/

Comment: @Matthiew: Effectively, mostly yes (but the real requirement is that must be able to read the debug symbol format if you want to use those).  I wasn't suggesting rusbi should accept the gdb answer, but it's still useful to have it, as those not using VS can find it useful when they discover this question.  The comment was a friendly jibe because you implied gcc only runs on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual C++ then look up [data breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx).

Comment: I just found it a minute ago, but thanks anyway! 
Should have googled a bit more before posting...

Answer (score 2):

Many debuggers can watch a particular memory location, and break whenever the contents of that location are changed. Not sure about your particular toolchain, but `gdb` certainly supports this.

Comment: gdb's scripting could particularly come in handy here.

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a tool that can detect problems like this. It's free, open source and easy to use.